# Integration: Defining the integrand as a part of the measure

Tags: integration, measure-theory, probability-distributions

Let $P$ be a probability measure supported on $\mathbb{R}$. I am integrating:

$$\int_{x \in \mathbb{R}} c(x) \mathrm{d} P(x)$$

for some $c:\mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$. I was wondering the extremely elementary question of:

> what conditions do I need on $c$ so that I can act like $c(x) P(x)$ is a new measure and the above integration can be written as$$\int_{x \in \mathbb{R}}\mathrm{d}(c(x) \cdot P(x)).$$

Comment: If $c$ is integrable and $>0$ would be the first things to come to mind.

Comment: what means $d(c(x)P(x))$?

Comment: @rubikscube09 thank you! Why do we need $>0$?

Comment: @Masacroso a new measure defined by $c(x) P(x)$

Comment: @Masacroso For example, if $c(x) = x^2$, then can I define a new measure $\mu(x) = x^2 \cdot P(x)$ and integrate $\int_x \mathrm{d} \mu(x)$?

Comment: @independentvariable - strictly speaking you don't, although most beginning definitions of measures specify nonnegativity. Unless you are working with signed or complex measures.

Comment: @rubikscube09 thank you!

Comment: @independentvariable oh, I see what you mean. You already have a measure defined by the integrand $x^2 P(dx)$, you dont need a different notation for this, that is, you can set $$\mu(A):=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbf{1}_{A}(x)x^2 P(dx)$$ for any measurable set $A$, and its easy to check that $\mu$ is a measure. If $c$ is a non-negative function you have non-negative measure (what is the standard notion of measure), but you can extend this definition to signed and complex measures as well, as far $\int_{\mathbb{R}}|c(x)|P(dx)<\infty $

Comment: in my previous comment I used accidentally a different notation, but they mean the same, that is, the notation $P(dx)$ means the same that the notation $dP(x)$. Im used to the first one, I hope it doesn't confuse you.

Comment: @Masacroso very clear, thank you very much. If you write this as an answer I would like to "accept" it. Also, I was actually wondering, is saying $\int_{x}  c(x) \mathrm{d} P(x) = \int_{x} \mathrm{d}[ c(x) P(x) ]$ wrong?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a measure space $(X, F, \mu)$, and $f : X \to [0, \infty]$ is measurable, then for $S \in F$,
$$\nu(S) = \int_{S}f(x)\,d\mu(x)$$
defines a measure $\nu$ on $F$. The proof is easy, just verify that $\nu$ satisfies the measure axioms. The common notation for $\nu$ is $d\nu = f\,d\mu$. This statement just means $\nu$ is defined as above. $f$ is commonly called the density function or Radon-Nikodym derivative of $\nu$ with respect to $\mu$. A typical case is when $\nu$ is a probability measure and $\mu$ is Lebesgue measure.